# Spring MVC not loading static files

Tags: css, spring, spring-mvc

**Issue:** Spring sometimes loads css and sometimes doesn't

When I run the project initially, I get the html without styles like so:

[image]

When I enter login credentials and hit Log in, it goes to this URL:

http://localhost:8080/project/resources/img/facebook.png

If I press the Back button (and it perform logout) it then gives me the form with css loaded such as:

[image]

And I am able to Log in as expected.

**My code:** In WebConfig.java

```
    @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/css/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/img/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/js/");
}
```

And in Login.jsp

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- styles -->
<link href="resources/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Any ideas why is that happening?

Comment: try `<link href="/resources/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @HadiJeddizahed, it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@Override
protected void addResourceHandlers( ResourceHandlerRegistry registry ) {
    registry.addResourceHandler( "/js/**", "/css/**", "/img/**" ).addResourceLocations( "classpath:js/", "classpath:css/", "classpath:img/" );
}
```

I assume that the folders : `js/`,`css/` and `img/` are in the the `resources` folder which already belongs to your classpath.